# Android voice to text example using registerForActivityResult instead of deprecated onActivityResult

Tags: android, voice

I am just learning the android environment.  I am trying to code a mobile app that converts speech to text and every example I find uses the deprecated "onActivityResult" function.  I cannot find an example that uses the new "registerForActivityResult" function.  Please help.

Thank you,

Arthur

Answer (score 0):

The request for permissions probably is for the RECORD_AUDIO permission. If so look into requesting this permissions [like it's done here.](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

---

On as side note - My advice - If you are stuck, ignore the deprecated warnings. Android is getting stuff deprecated every now and then. Don't wear yourself out searching for a solution for every deprecated warnings, because your new solution might get deprecated as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It was bothering me because I couldn't use Ctrl-O to find the "onActivityResult" method to override.  If I try to type "@Override" if flags as an error.  I think it's totally stupid for people to deprecate so freely and orphan existing working code.  Very unprofessional.

Comment: You will stumble upon more of this things. For instance the Firebase docs of adding auth to the android gradle file